# "unreachable code after return statement" error in Google Analytics JS code on Firefox - is this my fault?

Tags: debugging, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, developer-tools

I'm using the current Google Analytics tracking code, and on Firefox 59 I get this error in console:

> unreachable code after return statement

On this javascript: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-my-tracking-code:formatted

Since this problem doesn't seem to be googleable, hence it seems others do not have this problem, my guess is that it's me who does something wrong. But what this could be?

I'm putting the snippet in `<head>`, just like the docs say:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>some title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-my-tracking-code"></script>

        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', 'UA-my-tracking-code');
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
     blah blah 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same, did you find a fix?

Comment: @gurtfrobe - no, sorry, I didn't :(

Comment: Same here said firefox 60.0.1. Chrome is silent though :)

Comment: I believe this is only developer warning - JavaScript code and analytics works just fine.

Comment: @TadejP - yes, it is indeed, just like most of the things you can find in the console :) Logs and warnings. However, personally I do not expect a warning in case of a well established, production ready library made by one of the giants. My own warnings generated by my own libs being in development stage are quite enough for me:) But yes - it seems to work fine otherwise.

Comment: Same warning with firefox 60.0.2
Quite painful. Perfectly agree with Konrados (+1)

Comment: Same with FF 60.0b2 Dev Edition. 
Seems to work fine though. I Could not find additional info on that subject.

Comment: By the way that's a `<head>` not `<header>`, nonetheless, you have it in the correct element (`<head>`)

Comment: @Brandito - corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is *not* your fault. If you prettify the code with Firefox's it can be found here:

```
Gc = function (a, b, c) {
  var d = a.split('.');
  var e = function (a, b) {
    for (var c = 0; void 0 !== a && c < d.length; c++) {
      if (null === a) return !1;
      a = a[d[c]]
    }
    return void 0 !== a || 1 < c ? a : b.length ? e(Hc(b.pop()), b)  : Ic(d)
  };
  return e(Cc.eventModel, [         // <= True return value
    b,
    c
  ]);
  return Ic(d)  // <= This can never be reached!
},
```

To prettify the code:

1. Click on the warning's blue link. You'll see the garbled code.
2. Click on the icon with the `{}` on the bottom left of that panel to prettify it. However the reference will be lost.
3. Go back to the "Console" panel and click again in the same warning's blue link. Now you'll see the original reference in the correct line.

Firefox is correctly pointing the bug, the function `Ic(d)` will never be reached since the function returns earlier. Seems like a Google Tag Manager bug, however without inspecting the original code we cannot tell the severity.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I also found this specific reason eventually, although this doesn't solve the problem at hand:) Yet, you did your analysis and it seems this is the best thing we can do anyway (except maybe reporting the bug to google), so I marked this as an answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think you only upvoted my answer but did not marked it as "answer" though. That'd be the green check mark "✓".

Comment: Any updates on this? I am still getting this error in the Console until now.

Comment: Not really @JAT86... feel free to report this bug on the official Google channels.

Answer (score 3):

My OCD will not let this be. Warnings are as bad as errors to my brain... lol

The answer provided by @Me - caused me to perform the following:

1. Navigate to the url in the `<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={Google Analytics Id here}"></script>` tag and grab a copy of the JavaScript.
2. Drop it into a file in my solution and replace the remote js src with this new local copy.
3. Re-format the file (prettify).
4. Comment out the offending line (if it can't be reached as-is I don't expect terrible harm to come from simply removing it).

The warning is gone, and so far everything seems to be working - no additional or new errors/warnings in the console and Analytics/Tracking data still seems to be coming through.

This is clearly not an ideal solution - I'll have to continue monitoring this until either a) Google fixes their code (which, incidentally, omits semi-colons all over - I doubt it'd come close to passing a Linter) or b) Google makes other changes to the code, causing mine to break or my Analytics to stop reporting.

Comment: I'd be more afraid of the latter happening.

Comment: @Brandito I agree - but the first line of file in question is `// Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All rights reserved.` ... so I'm not holding my breath waiting for Google to fix this. And I have this on an Angular SPA right now which requires some additional code to track page changes - but as I said, everything is tracking and working fine right now. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The issue does not occur with all versions of the tracking code.

### gtag

This code snippet, using `gtag`, causes the `unreachable code after return statement` warnings (in Firefox):

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-YY"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-YY');
</script>
```

*Source: the Admin section in Google Analytics: `Admin › Tracking Info › Tracking Code`, last updated God knows when.*

### analytics.js

**This code snippet, using `analytics.js`, does not trigger the error:**

```
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-YY', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
```

Taken from the official documentation: *[Adding analytics.js to Your Site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#the_javascript_tracking_snippet)*  (second code sample), "Last updated July 30, 2018."

Remember to update `XXXXXX-YY` with your own property ID.

---

What are the differences?

From the Admin section:

> Global Site Tag (gtag.js) and Google Tag Manager are the recommended tracking methods for new implementations. Additional implementation options are also available including analytics.js and the Measurement Protocol. Learn more about additional tracking methods.

[From the documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7538414#analyticsjs):

> Use analytics.js
>
> The gtag.js library is the recommended tracking code for new implementations. However, there may be cases where you would prefer to use analytics.js (e.g., your site already makes use of analytics.js.) See the developer documentation for more information.